Barcode Sticker Printing in Angular Web Application
I am working on the stock inventory angular web application. I want to generate and print the barcode label sticker for each of the stock items. I have generated the barcode. Now, I want to make a label sticker that has the content and barcode.
Do we have any library for the same in Angular? Or should I design using HTML and CSS?
Also following are the challenges I am facing in developing this feature:

Labels are of multiple sizes, so I have planned to make templates like rectangle labels (2:1, 1:2), and square labels (1:1) . Now what if the label is of some other ratio? Or is there any other way to develop dynamic label sizes?
There are multiple companies that builds printers specially for labels. So how to support the different printer companies?

I tried to design using HTML and CSS, but it is not dynamic and fails if an existing label is of a different size.
Can anyone please direct me on this or share some links for the same?

Also, If ratio 1:1 is selected, then size can be either 1x1inch or 2x2inch. How to change the fonts size, weight dynamically depending on sticker size.

Supporting multiple printers companies is not an easy task.
I've made an Angular app where you can print barcode sticker for the Dymo printer device.
It includes many things just to support one company, here is what I did for Dymo :

Include the specific library in your project -> Dymo.js
Install the web driver on your computer, it means your client need to have a specific driver on it's computer -> Dymo connect
Convert to barcode sticker to the correct XML format

After all, if you are able to print sticker from multiples printers device, the user will just have the second requirement to make it works (drivers).
He just have to choose which device he's using and your code will do the job.

Okay, I will check with my printer.
And how about dynamic sticker size? Like I need 3 different sizes - 2x2, 2x3 and 1.5x3 inches

How did you print 10 stickers in a line?
